# How to copy GSI image from Android phone to Windows PC?

Tags: android, adb

I have downloaded a GSI image in my phone (Realme 7i) through DSU (Dynamic System Update). For some reason, I want to keep this image in my Windows 11 PC as a backup for later use (If possible, to flash it by using SDK platform tool later).
Each time I boot my phone, I see a screen with a message "Dynamic System Upade is ready. To start using it, restart your device" with Restart and Discard options.
So, before going to discard I want to keep a backup of the image. I dont know even in which location(internal storage) in my phone, this image is downloaded.
I am new to it. Any light on it will be appreciated.

Comment: DSU features require a system with "Dynamic Partitions" active, therefore one can assume that the content is written to an partition. Not sure if the DSU system contains an interface for reading the DSU partition data, because without you would need root to read a partition content.